# How to extract input id of a checkbox in selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract if one checkbox is checked or not using below code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='checkbox-410']")
print (element.is_selected())
```

The problem i am facing is the id for that checkbox is updating every time as i need to do this multiple times. Below is html code where it was at once 339 and next it becomes some different number

```
<input id="checkbox-339" type="checkbox" label="Stoploss" class="su-checkbox" value="true">
```

Is it possible if i can check whether checkbox is checked or not using div, I mean there is only one checkbox in that div:

```
//*[@id="app"]/form/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]
```

Or if any other way to do this, please suggest?

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@label='checkbox-410']")
```

Try using

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Stoploss")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with little update: "element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@label='Stoploss']")"

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle this :

```
//input[@label='Stoploss']
```

or if you wanna stick with `id`, maybe this could help :-

```
//input[contains(@id, 'checkbox-')]
```

and if there are multiple entries with `//input[contains(@id, 'checkbox-')]`, you can apply xpath index as well.

```
(//input[contains(@id, 'checkbox-')])[1]
```

or

```
(//input[contains(@id, 'checkbox-')])[2]
```

or so on..